# Add active state to menu item on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've seen a few topics regarding this issue. I added them, changed to my site specific classes and such, however I'm not seeing it working. Therefor, hopefully you can create a custom function for it for me.

I'm having [this website](http://checkspot.nl/appendo/website) and I'm looking for a way to have each menu item have an active state `('.active')` based upon the scroll position on the site.

**Summarized version of my site**

```
<nav id="topMenu">
  <ul class="right-side">
    <a href="#sectionA">Section A</a>
    <a href="#sectionB">Section B</a>
    <a href="#sectionC">SectionC</a>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="sectionA">
    content...
</section>

<section id="sectionA">
    content...
</section>

<section id="sectionA">
    content...
</section>
```

I'm unsure whether you need more information about my page HTML layout, although you can simple open the page and check the source.

Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: You should show some jQuery code.

Comment: Why/what kind of jQuery code? - I've added the jQuery tag because this can only be done with jQuery (/or javascript) - if that is what you mean.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself?

Comment: As written, I've checked about 5+ snippets that did the trick, but didn't seem to work. I do know how to track page height and scroll position, but not how to bind that to a menu item to add an active state. I lack skills to get this working myself. That's why I'm asking you guys.

Comment: Worth checking out - [Bootstrap scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/).

Comment: @Pete What's the point of wrapping each `a` within the `nav` inside a `li` element, as the current behavior is perfect?

Comment: @pete Well, honestly.. It simply could be put inside a `div` instead of an `ul` and than it's valid HTML. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Pete your fiddle, same as the fiddle @ilovecode has linked to are kind of working. The current menu item gets a active state, however.. it doesn't change on scroll, somehow. And it doesn't matter if I wrap the whole javascript within a `$(function () {});`, `$(window).scroll(function () {});` or just not wrapped at all.. That's yet all I can the information I can give.. Kind of vague, I'm aware of that..

Comment: @Pete I've got it working. Post your suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it as complete - **Slight update though!** What should be adjusted that it won't remove an active state until a new one is to mark active? There are some sections that haven't been added to the menu, which results in at some points there is no menu item highlighted..

Comment: While you try, I'm trying within my code editor.. :) - Thanks in advance! I've noticed btw you were at up to 150 variations in your fiddle (`http://jsfiddle.net/GBbu6/150/`), hehe, nice..

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks very much! (it's starting to look nice! Updated the live version for if you'd like to check out. :) Note: I'm currently updating the whole CSS for the topmenu. You might find a 'bug' I haven't added in CSS. Don't worry about that :)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Sorry this comment is so late, but how did you get this to work? I'm having the same problem, and I don't want to have to use scrollspy if I don't have to.

Comment: @NojoRu, strangely, Pete has removed all it's comments (or account deleted..) which included the how and why. However, I opened the case I needed this for and copied the relevant jQuery code and posted it as an answer. See it below. Don't forget to add a .active CSS class with style attributes :) - Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work out. I can't recall anymore why it works.. I recommend to study the beneath code and try it out yourself.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop() + 55;
    links.removeClass('active');
    lis.removeClass('active');

    sections.each(function() {
        var top = $(this).offset().top,
            bottom = top + $(this).height() + 100;

        if (currentPosition >= top && currentPosition <= bottom) {
            var link = $('a[href="#' + this.id + '"]');
            link.addClass('active');
            link.parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
});
```